# Kotlin to chain multiple sequences from different InputStream?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

Say if I want to parse a large file like this :

```
val iStream = MyFile::class.java
    .getResourceAsStream("largeFile.txt")

iStream.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).useLines { lines ->
    lines.filterNot { it.startsWith("#") }
    // parseing
    .toSet()
}
```

But if I want to split the largeFile to multiple smaller files , how to chain the sequences ?

For example :

```
val seq1 = MyFile::class.java.getResourceAsStream("file1.txt")
    .use { it.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).lineSequence() }
val seq2 = MyFile::class.java.getResourceAsStream("file2.txt")
    .use { it.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).lineSequence() }

sequenceOf(seq1, seq2).flatten()
  .filterNot { it.startsWith("#") }
  // parsing
  .toSet()
```

It will throw `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` , which is reasonable , because the parsing is outside the `scope` of the `use` block.

How to solve the problem ?

I know there may be some **nesting** solution (nesting `useLines` ... ) , but I think that is ugly . Is there any other `flat` solutions ?

Comment: Clearly, you must expand the resources' scope. Since you want a flat solution, you must choose to either have an upper-level scope that covers both files or to give up scoped resource management and just leave the files open, maintain references to them, and close them after the processing is done.

Comment: Is there any code snippets for this ? How to create a scope that auto close two(or more) input stream ?

Comment: [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-there-standard-way-to-use-multiple-resources/2613), this look really good.

Answer (score 2):

You could invert your logic. Important is, that everything is got or handled within the `use` otherwise that will not work, as you already know.

One such ~invertion could look like:

```
setOf("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
  .map { MyFile::class.java.getResourceAsStream(it) }
  .flatMap {
    it.use {
      it.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8)
        .lineSequence()
        .filterNot { it.startsWith("#") }
        .toSet()
    }
  }
```

Or if you want to pass the chain transformation or filter from outside, maybe something like:

```
val handleLine : (Sequence<String>) -> Sequence<String> = {
  it.filterNot { it.startsWith("#") }
  // .map { ... whatever }
}
setOf("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
  .map { MyFile::class.java.getResourceAsStream(it) }
  .flatMap {
    it.use {
      handleLine(it.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).lineSequence())
        .toSet()
    }
  }
```

The other alternative is to open up the streams, omit `use` and finally close them yourself as also @MarkoTopolnik pointed out in the comments:

```
val inputStreams = sequenceOf("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
  .map { MyFile::class.java.getResourceAsStream(it) }

inputStreams.flatMap { it.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8).lineSequence() }
  .filterNot { it.startsWith("#") }
  .toSet()
```

Then either use:

```
inputStreams.forEach(InputStream::close) // but this will fail on the first error...
```

or the "safe" way:

```
inputStreams.forEach { try { it.close() } catch (e: Exception) { e.printStackTrace() } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same thing, I've got lots of big files and want to process them sequentially. You can wrap file processing into a coroutine (e.g. sequence builder) so it will keep the stream while returning lines.

Here I'm traversing a directory and print all the lines:

```
val base = File("....")

base.walkTopDown()
        .filter { it.isFile }
        .flatMap { file -> sequence {
                file.useLines { lines ->
                    lines.forEach { yield(it) }
                }
            }
        }
        .forEach { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I had a pretty similar problem.
I had to process each line from multiple files the same way. I didn't want to go through individual files, but rather get all the lines as a sequence.
Here's my approach:

```kotlin
    fun main() {
        println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath())
        val filenames = listOf("file1", "file2")
        val lines = sequence {
            filenames
                    .asSequence()
                    .map { LoggingReader(File(it)) }
                    .forEach {
                        it.useLines { yieldAll(it) }
                    }
        }
        lines.forEachIndexed { i, line -> println("$i $line") }
    }
    
    class LoggingReader(val file: File) : BufferedReader(file.bufferedReader()) {
        init {
            println("$file - open")
        }
    
        override fun close() {
            super.close()
            println("$file - closed")
        }
    }
```

This code gives

```
    file1 - open
    0 file1-1
    1 file1-2
    2 file1-3
    file1 - closed
    file2 - open
    3 file2-1
    4 file2-2
    5 file2-3
    file2 - closed
```

**Note** This line is very important `.asSequence()`. Without the line it will process the entire `.map` statement before `.foreach`. This way it will open all the files before any read. Below is the output of this case.

```
    file1 - open
    file2 - open
    0 file1-1
    1 file1-2
    2 file1-3
    file1 - closed
    3 file2-1
    4 file2-2
    5 file2-3
    file2 - closed
```