# What is the equivalent of Files.lines() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an equivalent of Java Files.lines() in Kotlin ?

The Java code I would like to convert is similiar to

```java
Stream<String> lines =
  Files.list(Paths.get(dir_in))
  .flatMap((Files::lines));

// do something with my stream

lines.close();
```

I'm interested in the ability to release all the files system resources by closing the Stream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/use-lines.html. or you can just use the same thing in Kotlin than what you use in Java.

Comment: First and foremost, in Java use `try-with-resources`!!

Comment: I tried File::useLines already but it does not return a sequence and when I "trick" it to return a sequence () it cannot be used because the resource is closed (as documented on useLines)

Comment: The whole idea is to use the sequence inside of the block, precisely to make sure it's always safely closed, unlike what your Java code does. But again, you can use Streams in Kotlin.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - You are right, Stream implements AutoCloseable. But the Java code here is just for illustration purpose

Comment: I have used the technique from this post for now :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640194/kotlin-to-chain-multiple-sequences-from-different-inputstream

Answer (score 0):

I would use `File#bufferedReader`

It returns a `BufferedReader`, which you can  (a) close when you want and (b) get the stream of lines with `BufferedReader#lines`.

Here's some example code.

```
val buffer: BufferedReader = File("hi.txt").bufferedReader()
val stream: Stream<String> = buffer.lines()
stream.forEach { println(it) }
buffer.close()
```

You should use the `File#useLines` function whenever possible, as it auto-closes the steam.