# Kotlin Path.useLines { } - How not to get IOException("Stream closed")?

Tags: kotlin, iterator, line, sequence

Kotlin has nice wrappers and shortcuts, but sometimes I get caught not understanding them.

I have this simplified code:

```kotlin
class PipeSeparatedItemsReader (private val filePath: Path) : ItemsReader {
    override fun readItems(): Sequence<ItemEntry> {

        return filePath.useLines { lines -> 
            lines.map { ItemEntry("A","B","C","D",) } 
        }
}
```

And then I have:

```
    val itemsPath = Path(...).resolve()
    val itemsReader = PipeSeparatedItemsReader(itemsPath)

    for (itemEntry in itemsReader.readItems())
        updateItem(itemEntry)

    // I have also tried itemsReader.readItems().forEach { ... }
```

Which is quite straightforward - I expect this code to give me a sequence which opens a file and reads the lines, parses them, and gives `ItemEntry`s, and when used up, close the file.

What I get, however, is `IOException("Stream closed")`.

Somehow, even before the first item is read (I have debugged), somewhere within Kotlin's wrappers, the `reader.in` becomes null, so this exception is thrown in `hasNext()`.

I have seen a similar question here:  [Kotlin to chain multiple sequences from different InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640194/kotlin-to-chain-multiple-sequences-from-different-inputstream)

That one includes a lot of Java boilerplate which I would like to avoid.

**How should I code this sequence using `Path.useLines()`?**

Comment: In short: I can't. The `use*` helpers, by design, close the resource at the end of *their* call, not at when the sequence is processed (as it may sounds from the current KDoc). Thanks @Joffrey for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Kotlin helper with "use" in the name closes the underlying resource at the end of the lambda you pass (at least that's a convention in the stdlib as far as I know). The most common example being [AutoCloseable.use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html).

The [Path.useLines](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/use-lines.html) extension is no exception:

> Calls the block callback giving it a sequence of all the lines in this file and **closes the reader once the processing is complete.** [emphasis mine]

This means `useLines` closes the sequence of lines once the block is done, and thus you cannot return a lazy sequence out of it because you can't use it after the `useLines` function returns.

So, if you want to return a sequence of lines for later use, you cannot return a transformed sequence from that of `useLines` directly. Sequences actually cannot detect when someone is done using them, hence why `useLines` needs a lambda to give a "scope" or "lifetime" to the sequence and know when to close the underlying reader.

If you want to wrap this, you have 2 major options: either split the sequence operation and the close operation (make your `PipeSeparatedItemsReader` closeable), or use a lambda to process things in-place in `readItems()` the same way `useLines` does.

Comment: Thanks! But then - the term `processing` is quite misleading. By processing a sequence, I understand that I iterated over all items the sequence has to give. Therefore, I expected the file to be closed ***after*** the last line. Is there any set of wrappers around files that would work that way, without me writing the boilerplate? I mean, It's quite reasonable expectation to be able to process large files sequentially with just 1 line wrapper, isn't it?

Comment: Also, is there any dictionary that would explain what the KDoc means by things like "processing a sequence"? Or does the processing refer to the block? This should be clarified.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my initial "fix", please see the updated answer. The term "processing" is indeed misleading, the docs could be improved by being more clear about the fact that the reader is closed at the end of the passed lambda.

Comment: *Therefore, I expected the file to be closed after the last line.* - the problem is that, with a sequence, you cannot guarantee that the consumer of the sequence will reach the last line. For instance using `take`, or `first`, or other short-circuiting helpers would end the collection early and not reach the end, and in that case you don't want to leave the reader hanging.

Comment: Right, that would open the code for memory/FD leaks. That's what I was also wondering.  
I suggest to add a link into the KDoc to some general sequences utils references - could save time to many. (Although it's 2 clicks away in the code when knowing what to look for...)

Comment: So: 1) There is no such thing as `ClosableSequence` which could propagate a request to close, right?  2) Therefore, for lazy iterating, I will need to use `seqence { ... }` and some form of `yield()`, so that the lambda can "survive" while iterating? Which also means that I take the responsibility to consume the sequence fully? And how should be the premature closing be passed? Should I leak the `Reader` from within the lambda and store it in the now `Closable`  `PipeSeparatedItemsReader` ? That seems odd.

Comment: Because now I have `return Files.newBufferedReader(filePath).use { ... } `. But that hits the same issue. So I guess I can't use `use*` at all to create a lazy "pipeline" through my API. `use` is simply a thing that blocks and closes, by concept. Correct?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes you got everything right here. So as I said in the answer I think you can either store a reader as a property in `PipeSeparatedItemsReader`, and make the wrapper class closeable to close the underlying reader, or you can make your method take a lambda instead of returning a sequence, to shift the problem up (hopefully to a place where people control the entire lifetime of the sequence).